# How can I modify the fields appearing in a "Category" block of RSS feeds?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

I'm working on a Drupal 7 website, on a multisite installation (which might be important, since it means that I am not allowed to modify the core modules)

I have configured the aggregator, ceating a Category, and 2 feeds attached to this category. Then I have configured the block corresponding to this category to show up in the right sidebar, and it all works fine.

**BUT in this block, only the title of each news item is displayed, and I find it confusing. I would like to configure it so that the name of the source feed would be displayed alongside the news item title.**

I have looked carefully to the parametres of the Aggregator, and nothing seems to allow me to configure the fields to display in the block. I have checked in views too, but this block doens't seem to be built on a view.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are very limited in what you can customize on the default block for aggregator. You will need to write a custom view to get a customized block. Not sure of your experience with views, but if you need help with it there are tons of very good tutorials out there for views. (I especially like lullabots.)

Comment: Thank you toddsler! I'm quite OK with using views, but it's sad the built-in aggregator can't be customised a bit :(